# How to launch Python application without installation?

Tags: python, installation, py2exe

I have python scripts. They have to run on the machines without python, so I compile py scripts to executables using py2exe. Python with py2exe should be installed to perform compilation. But I want to be able to compile it on any machine without python installation.

So, is there any way to run python application on Windows without installation?

**UPD. I know that compiled by py2exe binaries will run without python. I'm asking how to launch py2exe without python?**

Ok, the answer is clear - there is no way. And we came back to first question:

**UPD2. How to run python (to launch py2exe on it) without installation?**

Comment: You don't need to have Python installed to run a py2exe binary. That's really the whole point of py2exe.

Comment: @Blender Do you mean py2exe bynary or the binaries generated by py2exe?  I know the only way to use py2exe:    python setup.py py2exe    . And this way requires python installation.

Comment: Yes, but don't you click on the EXE file afterwards to run your script?

Comment: @Blender sorry, looks like I didn't asked properly. Look at my updated question.

Comment: Why do you need to run Py2exe without Python?

Comment: @Blender , I don't really need =) This is just what you said "You don't need to have Python installed to run a py2exe binary. That's really the whole point of py2exe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read the faq:

> py2exe can not be executed standalone (unfortunately), so you first
>   install it as usual Python package, then create a section in your
>   setup.py script. then just run distutils with corresponding commands.

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ

but you can run python without installing it:
http://www.portablepython.com/

Comment: Thank you! I hope this portable python will work somehow with additional modules like py2exe.

Answer (score 0):

The binaries you produce with py2exe won't require python be installed on the machines where you deploy your programs.  The same can be said of bbfreeze, pyinstaller, and cxfreeze.  If you're running into errors, you likely have hidden imports or other unresolved dependencies that didn't properly get bundled into your executable.